# What's the solution to the Edison / Ford "139" code in Assassin's Creed 2?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

One of the passwords in Assassin's Creed 2 deals with Thomas Edison and J.P. Morgan trying to discredit Nikola Tesla in order to prevent alternating current from freeing the people, or something like that.  I'm trying to unlock his secret code.

The code is 139 and according to the hint button, the symbols follow a base 3 pattern - "One dot, two dots, one line, one line and one dot, and so on", and the missing symbol has to fit that pattern.

When I align "One dot" with the number 1, the solution to 139 seems to be:

```
One dot
One Line
Three Lines
```

but when I enter that solution, I get a "Wrong code" indication.  When I align one dot with zero, the solution to 139 comes up as:

```
Two dots
One line and one dot
Three lines and one dot
```

And that code doesn't work either.

Usually there's a clue in the photos provided to explain how to align the cipher wheel, but I can't seem to find that either.  There's a symbol in the "Dearborn Independent" that contains two lines and two dots...does that have anything to do with it?

**What is the solution to the Edison / Ford 139 cipher, and what clue am I supposed to use to figure the solution out?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCHMJyc7z7M) shows the solution of the 12th glyph. The part you're asking for starts at 2:19.

[image: Two lines and a dot, three lines, one line and two dots]

The comment says that "there is the symbol in the newspaper article and the number on the left car."

Answer (score 1):

For this puzzle, you should:

- Align the 2 lines and 2 dots with the Number 2
- Use the missing symbols for F5 and F9 on the last two numbers

The number is on the car on the left, it has a circle around the number.